# serializing datatable source vb.net 2010

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

```
sql = "SELECT * from table"
da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conex)
dt = New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
Datos.DataSource = dt 'Until here it works - puts the data into a datagridview
MsgBox(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt).ToString)
```

I just want to serialize same data ... didn't show the msgbox at all...

As you can see I'm a noob in VB (2010) xD

Comment: And what is your exact question? What do you get and what do you want to get?

Comment: Im using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt).ToString to trying to serialize the data result from querry but i can make it work ...

Answer (score 0):

You either need to **add DataTable to a DataSet** and then serialize it as given in this article [SerializeDataSet](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDataSet.htm)

Or alternatively you need to **add its built-in DataTableConverter** to its settings as described here: [json-netserializing-a-datatable](http://chrish.com.au/blog/json-netserializing-a-datatable/)